# Refering a different sheets depending on the value in the cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sheet1 name is qwert. Sheet2 name is defgh. Sheet3 name is 12345.

So on sheet 'qwert'!B1 I am trying to pull depending on the left 5** characters in cell 'qwert'!A1

eg:

'qwert'A1 has value "defghijkl" then I want to refer to 'defgh'!A1

'qwert'A1 has value "123456789" then I want to refer to '12345'!A1

I am looking for something of this sort:

```
="'"left(A1,4)"'!A1"
```

I am sure there is a way to do this. Am just not sure how to do it.

**was 4, now corrected to 5 after Mrig highlighted the error :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you meant to say left 5 characters. Enter the following formula in `Cell B1` of sheet `qwert`

```
=INDIRECT("'" & LEFT(A1,5) & "'!A1")
```

`INDIRECT` function returns the reference specified by a text string. For details see [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261).

[image]